# Как инициализировать notificationManager в fragment android?

Tags: android, android-notification, android-push-notification

У меня есть приложение для работы с фрагментами, и одной из функций этого приложения является создание `notification`, но данный элемент будет создаваться не из обычной `activity`, а из `fragment`. То есть в фрагменте есть кнопка при нажатии на которую мы создаем `notification`. Проблема в том что я только начал работать с уведомлениями, и уже начинаю замечать некоторые отличия в инициализации элементов в классе `onCreate`. На данный момент я начал внедрять процесс создания уведомлений и нахожусь на начальном этапе, но я почему-то не могу инициализировать `NotificationManager`, ниже я привожу свой код:

```
public class First extends Fragment {
    Button notification;
    private NotificationManager nm;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        notification = view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        nm = getApplicationContext()
        notification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

как можно понять из кода, я не могу прописать `getApplicationContext` в классе `onCreate`. Может нужно где-то в другом месте инициализировать данный элемент для дальнейшей работы с ним. Буду благодарен за любую  полезную информацию и советы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    nm = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}
```